# TTS not stop in Service: stop failed: not bound to TTS engine

Tags: android, service, text-to-speech

My TTS in service is not stopping and speak two times.
In logcat the error is "stop failed: not bound to TTS engine"
I am stuck here that why TTS is not stoping. What wil I do here to stop it when speaked.
Here is my code

```
 public class Speaker extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
        public static TextToSpeech mtts;
        String speech = "";

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
            speech=intent.getExtras().getString("speech");
           mtts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);
        }


            @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
             if (mtts != null) {
                Log.e("Destroy", "Service");
                 mtts.stop();
                 mtts.shutdown();
                }

                super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
                    mtts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
            Log.e("onInit ends", "Service");
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: actually you have started the services which will run continuously either you should destroy the service after make it speak, else you should apply some condition statement to control it. Would you like to tell me what you want to do with this code

Comment: I start this service to speak incoming caller number. I start it from broadcast receiver.

Comment: Plz tell me how will I stop it? @PirFahimShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is that when a phone call is incoming then at this time your broadcast receiver would be calling this activity again and again unless you pick the phone
If you want to stop this service after make it speak for once.
Code for stopping the service.

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, Speaker.class);
 stopService(in);
```

Use this code inside onDestroy() or in onStart() method.
Why you are using the service for TTS?, you can use any activity or class etc.